# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' - ionic 3, angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

After I installed ngx-translate module into the ionic app and implemented translations all over the custom pages I can't build my app anymore.

When I run

```
$ ionic cordova build browser --prod
```

I get the following exception:

```
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform browser --target cordova
[15:30:02]  build prod started ... 
[15:30:02]  clean started ... 
[15:30:02]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[15:30:02]  copy started ... 
[15:30:03]  deeplinks started ... 
[15:30:03]  deeplinks finished in 207 ms 
[15:30:03]  ngc started ... 
[15:30:09]  ngc finished in 6.48 s 
[15:30:09]  preprocess started ... 
[15:30:09]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
[15:30:09]  webpack started ... 
[15:30:09]  copy finished in 6.93 s 
Error: ./src/app/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/projects/myApp/src/app'
resolve './app.module.ngfactory' in '/projects/myApp/src/app'
  using description file: /projects/myApp/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /projects/myApp/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    using description file: /projects/myApp/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.json doesn't exist
      as directory
        /projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory doesn't exist
[/projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory]
[/projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts]
[/projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js]
[/projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory.json]
[/projects/myApp/src/app/app.module.ngfactory]
 @ ./src/app/main.ts 2:0-60
    at new BuildError (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/webpack.js:121:28)
    at emitRecords.err (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (/projects/myApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/performance/SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (/projects/myApp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (/projects/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:365:9)
```

I tried every possible solution I could find on google and nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I tried with the most simple yet effective debugging strategy: removing all of the custom ionic pages from the app, adding them back one by one and continuously building the app. I found out I didn't use ngx-translate pipe correctly in one of the templates...

Answer (score 0):

Just Try adding the following AngularCompiler Options object containing

- 'entryModule' property which is the path to the main module
- 'genDir' property which is the file where the generated ngfactory files for your components and modules will go

in the **tsconfig.json** file if this is not specified it in the AOT plugin
Ex :

```
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./app/app.module#AppModule",
    "genDir": "../ngfactory"
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
  }
}
```

the above configuration solved the issue for me